# Maven WAR Overlays - including unpacked dependencies

Tags: maven-2, coldfusion, maven

I'm trying to set up a project using Maven and am a bit stuck with how to include some third party dependencies that need to be included unpacked in the resultant war file.

My project contains some custom ColdFusion code and includes Java dependencies, including ColdFusion packaged as a war file.  I then am attempting to include some 3rd party ColdFusion code, which I've installed in my maven repository packaged as a jar, but I actually want to deploy it unpacked in the resultant war file.  It's this unpacking of the 3rd party libraries that I'm stuck with.  I'd really like this to be done BEFORE the war is build, so that I can use war:exploded during the development.

Currently my pom.xml looks something like this:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-webapp</artifactId>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>my-webapp Maven Webapp</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- This is the war overlay -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.coldfusion</groupId>
            <artifactId>coldfusion</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.1</version>
            <type>war</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>  

        <!-- This is the 3rd party ColdFusion dependency -->    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.corfield</groupId>
            <artifactId>fw1</artifactId>
            <version>1.2RC2A</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

     </dependencies>
     <build>
        <finalName>my-webapp</finalName>
     </build>
  </project>
```

I've kind of got it doing what I want by modifying the build section as follows:

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>org.corfield</groupId>
                                <artifactId>fw1</artifactId>
                                <version>1.2RC2A</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}</outputDirectory>
                                <includes>**/*.cfc</includes>
                            </artifactItem>
                           </artifactItems>
                        <includes>**/*.cfc</includes>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The problem with this is that the package:unpack happens after the war is built, so the unpacked dependecies are not in the resulting war file.

I have also tried a few things with the assembly plugin and I came fairly close also by using something like this:

```
<assembly>
    <id>${project.artifactId}</id>
    <formats>
        <format>war</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <includes>
                <include>org.corfield:fw1</include>
            </includes>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </dependencySet>
        <dependencySet>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>org.corfield:fw1</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
            <outputDirectory>/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

However that created a second war file named something like my-webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-my-webapp.war as well as the my-webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war.  The my-webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-my-webapp.war also included my-webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war

At the end of the day I want my resultant war to look like:

```
org
 |-- corfield
    |-- framework.cfc
WEB-INF
 |-- lib
 |-- web.xml
index.cfm
```

(in reality there's a lot more to it than that, but that's enough to illustrate the point hopefully)

I think I'm pretty close but I'm just missing something I need.  I'd be extremely grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the `maven-dependency-plugin` approach, bind the `unpack` goal on the `prepare-package` phase (Maven 2.1+) instead of `package`.

#### References

- [Lifecycle Reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)

Comment: @AndrewMyers: You're welcome. And just in case, have a look at [this blog](http://printstacktrace.org/blog/2010/01/demo-of-m2eclipse-with-waroverlay/) (I didn't test this m2eclipse extension though).

Comment: I had not seen that - looks extremely promising.  I will check it out now!  Thanks!

Comment: link broken....

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [overlay](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) option with [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html)?  It esstentially allows you to unpack the ColdFusion war on top your site layout.  I've done this with a combination of ColdFusion 9.x and Struts2.  Doing a ColdFusion only overlay should make it real easy.  You may want to create the ColdFusion war first.  You can also then control the neo-*.xml files from your Maven project as well.

Comment: Sounds like you're doing exactly what I'm doing (although I'm using Spring, not Struts).  I am using the war overlay option as well.  Thanks for your answer but Pascal Thivent's answer was the one I was looking for.  What IDE are you using out of interest?  I think I'm going to settle for Intellij as Eclipse doesn't support Maven Overlays terribly well and Netbeans doesn't support CF...

Comment: I use the command line most of the time.  Have you upgraded the m2eclipse plugin to 0.10.x yet.  It's a lot better than the 0.9.x version.

Comment: Yes I've tried m2eclipse 0.10.x and also IAM (previously known as q4e).  IAM is supposed to do war overlays but I can't get it to work.  m2eclipse doesn't, and I couldn't get the extension that Pascal linked to above to work either.  The whole thing is very messy.

Comment: What version of Maven are you running?  2.2.x?  And what version of the maven war plug-in do you have specified?  Looks like you need a minimum of 2.1-alpha-1 specified for the war plug-in.